# Android Login Screen: Two-way binding EditText and TextView

Tags: android, mvvm, observable, mvp, android-databinding

Im trying to create a simple login screen with databinding for username+password. I only have one-way binding: I can set the bound variables in code and see them reflected in UI, but UI changes do not change the vars.

```
Activity
---
        ActivityLoginBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_login);
        binding.setLifecycleOwner(this);
        mViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(LoginViewModel.class);


ViewModel
---
public class UserViewModel {
    public ObservableField<String> username = new ObservableField<>("");
    public ObservableField<String> password = new ObservableField<>("");
    public ObservableField<Boolean> doRemember = new ObservableField<>(false);

    public UserViewModel(String username, String password, Boolean doRemember) {
        this.username.set(username);
        this.password.set(password);
        this.doRemember.set(doRemember);
    }
}

View
---
<EditText
                    android:text="@{userVm.username}"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
<TextView
                    android:text="@{userVm.username}"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

I found a website suggesting i use a TextWatcher ( https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/two-way-data-binding-on-android-observing-your-view-with-xml/ ) to achieve 2-way binding. This works, but is this really needed for every view i wanna bind to?! Isnt there an easier way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

oh there's a "@={}" syntax for two-way binding :O

```
android:text="@={userVm.username}"
```

instead of

```
android:text="@{userVm.username}"
```

works